# useing __FILE__ and locating root folder in php ? how do i do this?

Tags: php

lets say we have a directory.

project/index.php

in index.php

```
<?php
require 'config/config.php';
echo ROOTPATH;
?>
```

project/config/config.php

```
<?php
define('ROOTPATH', rtrim(dirname(__FILE__), '\\/'));
?>
```

it will return like
D:\Project Storage\Web Projects\www\project\config.

question:

1. is there an easy way to get the rootpath without puting it on the project folder ? ( i know this is supid but i cant stand to ask )
2. is there a way to get the \project\ ( root folder ) ? even if we change the folder location ?

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

ps*
please leave a comment if you dont understand what i mean.

Comment: are you trying to get current script folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`realpath()` ITs your friend.. for example:

in config/config.php

```
define('ROOTPATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..'));
```

Or to get the folder above project:

```
define('ROOTPATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../..'));
```

I dont work on windows, but if i recall `realapath` will sort out the slashes for you... if thats not the case then use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant for compatibility.

Comment: what does the /.. do ? and about the slashes '.DS.'..'.DS.' ? and how about http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary ?

Comment: @adam: `..` is standard for navigating up a directory relative tot he directory your in so for example `realpath('projects/somedir/..')` will eval to the absolute file system path to `projects`. `realpath` will remove any extra slashes in the path... the only thing you *might* need to worry about is if you are using \ or / but i think it sorts that out too - im just not 100% because on that because i only work on *nix systems.

Comment: Well then as per the article just use forward slashes :-)

Comment: ah i just got a new problem realpath('projects/somedir/../anotherfolder')
will go to project/anotherfolder ?

Comment: @adam: yep it will, how is that a problem? you should make a new question with your issue... and include the specific paths your trying to calcualte and from where in the dir tree you are.